# Jackson: How to serialise date as dd/MMM/yy

Tags: jackson

I am able to parse the above date format successfully with the following annotations on the getter and setter:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MMM/yy")
 @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
 @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
```

However when it comes time to serialise the data back to JSON a date of, for example, `23/Oct/18` gets turned into `2018-10-23`. I was under the impression Jackson would use the formatting hints during serialisation as well but this is not the case.

How do I go about serialising to the `dd/MMM/yy` format so I can send back dates in the same format I fetch them?

Comment: I was able to do this using a custom serialiser so I can add that as an answer if there is no out-of-the-box support for dd/MMM/yy

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use?

Comment: I am using Jackson 2.9.6 (as bundled with Dropwizard 1.3.7)

Comment: I have tried it with version [2.9.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.8) and [JavaTimeModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) module and it works properly.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I’ll try with 2.9.8 as well

Comment: Using vanilla Jackson outside of Jersey (and Dropwizard) it works out-of-the-box :/ So it might be Jersey client is doing something when the requests get sent out in their serialised form.